# resizing image in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want my screen to look like [image: this]
but I am getting [image: this] after various try.

Here is my code:-

```
<ImageBackground 
      style={styles.imageBackground}
      source={constants.image.bg_splash}
    >
```

Style:-

```
 imageBackground: {
 // flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center',
  //  width:'90%',
  //  //height:constants.DesignHeight-300,
  //  height:'100%',
  // marginVertical:40,
   resizeMode:'contain',
  // borderWidth:1,
  // borderColor:'black',
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  right: 0,
 },
```

Commented code are the parts which I have tried as various combination.

Thanks!!!

Comment: the issue is the grey shape behind the text?

Comment: Can you attach a raw background image to your question?

Comment: yes issue is with grey background.

Comment: @ShanAlam did you have a chance to look into our solutions? if any answer helps, please mark it as useful

Comment: I tried but it does not help me as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, your background is the gray shape and you want to have this white vertical padding which is not a part of your gray shape image. To achieve this you can wrap your component in the following way:

```js
// https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview

<SafeAreaView>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground 
      style={styles.imageBackground}
      source={constants.image.bg_splash}
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    position: relative,
    paddingVertical: 40,
  },
  imageBackground: {
    // https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#absolutefillobject
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to position the ImageBackground as absolute. Give it a width and height of device and resizeMode: contain.

```
imageBackground: {
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  resizeMode: 'contain',
}
```